# Inserting Text into an Active Minibuffer

Tags: emacs, minibuffer

I'm trying to insert text into the mini buffer after running an external command. E.G

```
(call-interactively 'eval-expression)
(insert "blah")
```

The problem of course is that eval-expression doesn't return before the user has entered input. My end goal is to add some default *editable* text into the mini buffer prompt of an arbitrary command (i.e a 'default string' or template). How can I go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `minibuffer-setup-hook`:

```
(defun foo () (insert "ABCDE"))

(add-hook 'minibuffer-setup-hook 'foo)
```

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish this temporarily without having to add/remove the hook each time the function call is made? I only want this behavior when a custom function of mine is used.

Comment: Just add/remove each time you need to do it "temporarily". It is not costly. Put the add/remove code in whatever function you use that needs it.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to make sure there isn't a more idiomatic way to do it (adding/removing a hook seems wasteful somehow)

Comment: Nope, that's the idiomatic way: add/remove for the hook.