# How to set the default regexp value of the command isearch-forward-regexp?

Tags: search, emacs

For example: I want the regexp `^\*.*` to appear as the search pattern after typing `M-x isearch-forward-regexp` and `<return>`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
(defun foo ()
  (cond
   ((string= (minibuffer-prompt) "Regexp search: ")
    (insert "^\\*.*"))))
(add-hook 'minibuffer-setup-hook 'foo)
```

1. Press `C-M-s` and `<return>`, then the regexp `^\*.*` will appear as the search pattern.
2. Complement the full regexp (such as `^\*.*emacs`) and `<return>`.
3. Press `C-M-s` and `C-s` to search incrementally.

References:

- [Inserting Text into an Active Minibuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36118899/inserting-text-into-an-active-minibuffer)
- https://superuser.com/questions/221829/in-emacs-why-can-i-not-paste-text-c-y-into-a-c-s-search-box